# dsc command for iis service availability on iis

Tags: powershell, iis, winrm, dsc

I started using DSC configuration on power shell using Windows PowerShell ISE for deployment activities. I have a Windows 2012 web server which has IIS installed on it. On this IIS server, I have 12 services installed and running.

Now I am updating the code bits of one of the services on this IIS. Before I do that; I want to stop the IIS if it is running. IS there any command for this?

I tried the below command, but it checks only abt the IIS:

```ps1
WindowsFeature IIS 
{ 
  Ensure = "Present"
  Name = "Web-Server" 
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking. Consider that the purpose of DSC is to *describe* the *desired state* of the node. If it's not in that state, then set that state. You can use a [`Service` resource](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282120.aspx) to ensure that a service is stopped, but it won't be based on a condition. Please edit your question to better describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @briantist thanks for the tip. I don't certainly need a condition..this one works too.

Comment: If you need to stop and start iis as part of your update, you will need to either use a script resource or a custom DSC resource to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably should do is stop the default website as your configuration should describe the state you want.  You shouldn't want to install IIS just to stop it, but you probably don't want the default site.

Here is a configuration to do that:

```ps1
Configuration Sample_xWebsite_StopDefault
{
    param
    (
        # Target nodes to apply the configuration
        [string[]]$NodeName = 'localhost'
    )
    # Import the module that defines custom resources
    Import-DscResource -Module xWebAdministration
    Node $NodeName
    {
        # Install the IIS role
        WindowsFeature IIS
        {
            Ensure          = "Present"
            Name            = "Web-Server"
        }
        # Stop the default website
        xWebsite DefaultSite
        {
            Ensure          = "Present"
            Name            = "Default Web Site"
            State           = "Stopped"
            PhysicalPath    = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
            DependsOn       = "[WindowsFeature]IIS"
        }
    }
}
```